# Cron jobs are affected due to system upgrade error in magento 2. Did any one face this kind of issue?

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5-p1

Recently we upgraded to 2.3.3 to 2.3.5-p1. Most of of cron jobs are get affected with error message as **"The job is terminated due to system upgrade"**

[image]

Even though I commented out update/cron.php in crontab, still this issue coming. We are not sure what is this issue about and why it keep occurring. Magento also not provided a correct answers for this issue.
Any one faced such kind of issue?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Anyone got this solutions ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj did you find any answer for this?

Comment: Wrote to magento and they provided a patch for it. In 2.4 this issue is not there as per their statement